# Clicking A Link And Auto Scrolling

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website with a navigation bar on the left of screen, completely filled with 'a' tags that are linked to anchor tags.

While using my website, you will be going to different pages that don't have the grand list of songs you need on them like the home page does.

What I want to happen is on these sub-pages, clicking the 'a' tag takes you to the homepage, then, without you having to press anything again, automatically scrolls to its corresponding anchor tag.

For example, you would click on "All Of Me - John Legend" and it would take you to that page with the info.
Then (while STILL on the "All of Me" page) you would click on "G" in the navigation bar and it would take you to the home page AND scroll down to the "G Songs" section.

Here is my code, and thanks for the help!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
 <head>
     <link href="E:/Website/namethatartist/styles/Index_Styling.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <link href="E:/Website/namethatartist/styles/Hover-master/css/hover.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
     <link href="E:/Website/namethatartist/styles/animate.css-master/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <title>Name That Artist</title>
     <meta name="author" content="Hunter Casteel" />
 </head>

<style>
    html, body {
     margin: 0;
 }

 /* Navigation Menu Styling */
 ul.main-menu {
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     width: 25%;
     background-color: #f1f1f1;
     position: fixed;
     height: 100%;
     overflow: auto;
 }

 ul.main-menu li a {
     display: block;
     color: #000;
     text-decoration: none;
     height:3.29999vh;
     font-size:2.2vh;
     padding:0.15vh 10%;
     font-family: Times New Roman;
 }

 ul.main-menu li a.active {
     background-color: #ef402c;
     color: white;
 }

 li a:hover:not(.active) {
     background-color: #555;
     color: white;
 }

 /* Text Styling */
 h1, h2, p {
    font-family: Calibri
 }

 p a:link, p a:visited{
     font-family: Times New Roman;
     color: black;
     text-decoration: none;
 }

 p a:hover {
    color: red;
 }

 a {
     padding: 2vh 2vh 1px 1px;
 }
 </style>

 <body background="E:/Website/namethatartist/media/images/paper.jpg">
     <ul class="main-menu">
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="#a_songs">A</a></li>
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="#b_songs">B</a></li>
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="#c_songs">C</a></li>
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="#d_songs">D</a></li>
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="#e_songs">E</a></li>
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="#f_songs">F</a></li>
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="#g_songs">G</a></li>
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="#h_songs">H</a></li>
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="#i_songs">I</a></li>
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="#j_songs">J</a></li>
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="#k_songs">K</a></li>
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="#l_songs">L</a></li>
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="#m_songs">M</a></li>
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="#n_songs">N</a></li>
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="#o_songs">O</a></li>
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="#p_songs">P</a></li>
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="#q_songs">Q</a></li>
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="#r_songs">R</a></li>
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="#s_songs">S</a></li>
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="#t_songs">T</a></li>
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="#u_songs">U</a></li>
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="#v_songs">V</a></li>
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="#w_songs">W</a></li>
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="#x_songs">X</a></li>
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="#y_songs">Y</a></li>
         <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="#z_songs">Z</a></li>
     </ul>

     <div style="margin-left:25%;padding:1px 16px;height:1000px;">
         <hr id="home"/><hr/>
         <h1 class="hvr-underline-from-center animated tada">Welcome To Name That Artist</h2>
         <button style="float:right;" class="animated hvr-pop" action="logInPage.php">Log In</button>
         <p> You can find information about a song from the wide selection we offer.</p>
         <h3>Use the navigation bar on the left to jump to songs with that first letter.</h3>
         <hr id="a_songs"/><hr/><p align="center">A</p><hr/>
             <div>
                 <p>
                     <a id="all_of_me_john_legend" class="hvr-float-shadow" href="songs/a/All_Of_Me_John_Legend.html">All Of Me - John Legend</a>
                 </p>
             </div>
         <hr id="b_songs"/><hr/><p align="center">B</p><hr/>
             <div>
                 <p>
                     <a id="bad_blood_bastille" class="hvr-float-shadow" href="songs/b/Bad_Blood_Bastille.html">Bad Blood - Bastille</a>
                     <a href="songs/b/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/b/.html"> </a>
                 </p>
             </div>
         <hr id="c_songs"/><hr/><p align="center">C</p><hr/>
             <div>
                 <p>
                     <a id="cake_by_the_ocean_dnce" class="hvr-float-shadow" href="songs/c/Cake_By_The_Ocean_DNCE.html">Cake By The Ocean - DNCE</a>
                     <a href="songs/c/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/c/.html"> </a>
                 </p>
             </div>
         <hr id="d_songs"/><hr/><p align="center">D</p><hr/>
             <div>
                 <p>
                     <a id="dont_stop_believin_journey" class="hvr-float-shadow" href="songs/d/Dont_Stop_Believin_Journey.html">Don't Stop Believin' - Journey</a>
                     <a href="songs/d/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/d/.html"> </a>
                 </p>
             </div>
         <hr id="e_songs"/><hr/><p align="center">E</p><hr/>
             <div>
                 <p>
                     <a id="eye_of_the_tiger_survivor" class="hvr-float-shadow" href="songs/e/Eye_Of_The_Tiger_Survivor.html">Eye Of The Tiger - Survivor</a>
                     <a href="songs/e/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/e/.html"> </a>
                 </p>
             </div> 
         <hr id="f_songs"/><hr/><p align="center">F</p><hr/>
             <div>
                 <p>
                     <a id="feel_good_robin_thicke" class="hvr-float-shadow" href="songs/f/Feel_Good_Robin_Thicke.html">Feel Good - Robin Thicke</a>
                     <a href="songs/f/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/f/.html"> </a>
                 </p>
             </div>
         <hr id="g_songs" class="revealOnScroll animated bounce"/><hr/><p align="center">G</p><hr/>
             <div>
                 <p>
                     <a id="geronimo_sheppard" class="hvr-float-shadow" href="songs/g/Geronimo_Sheppard.html">Geronimo - Sheppard</a>
                     <a href="songs/g/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/g/.html"> </a>
                 </p>
             </div>
         <hr id="h_songs"/><hr/><p align="center">H</p><hr/>
             <div>
                 <p>
                     <a id="here_alessia_cara" class="hvr-float-shadow" href="songs/h/Here_Alessia_Cara.html">Here - Alessia Cara</a>
                     <a href="songs/h/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/h/.html"> </a>
                 </p>
             </div>
         <hr id="i_songs"/><hr/><p align="center">I</p><hr/>
             <div>
                 <p>
                     <a id="i_write_sins_not_tragedies_panic_at_the_disco" class="hvr-float-shadow" href="songs/i/I_Write_Sins_Not_Tragedies_Panic_At_The_Disco.html">I Write Sins Not Tragedies - Panic! At The Disco</a>
                     <a href="songs/i/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/i/.html"> </a>
                 </p>
             </div>
         <hr id="j_songs"/><hr/><p align="center">J</p><hr/>
             <div>
                 <p>
                     <a id="just_give_me_a_reason_pink" class="hvr-float-shadow" href="songs/j/Just_Give_Me_A_Reason_Pink.html">Just Give Me A Reason - P!nk</a>
                     <a href="songs/j/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/j/.html"> </a>
                 </p>
             </div>
         <hr id="k_songs"/><hr/><p align="center">K</p><hr/>
             <div>
                 <p>
                     <a id="kill_of_the_night_gin_wigmore" class="hvr-float-shadow" href="songs/k/Kill_Of_The_Night_Gin_Wigmore.html">Kill Of The Night - Gin Wigmore</a>
                     <a href="songs/k/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/k/.html"> </a>
                 </p>
             </div>
         <hr id="l_songs"/><hr/><p align="center">L</p><hr/>
             <div>
                 <p>
                     <a id="latch_disclosure" class="hvr-float-shadow" href="songs/l/Latch_Disclosure.html">Latch - Disclosure</a>
                     <a href="songs/l/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/l/.html"> </a>
                 </p>
             </div>
         <hr id="m_songs"/><hr/><p align="center">M</p><hr/>
             <div>
                 <p>
                     <a id="me_and_my_broken_heart_rixton" class="hvr-float-shadow" href="songs/m/Me_And_My_Broken_Heart_Rixton.html">Me And My Broken Heart - Rixton</a>
                     <a href="songs/m/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/m/.html"> </a>
                 </p>
             </div>
         <hr id="n_songs"/><hr/><p align="center">N</p><hr/>
             <div>
                 <p>
                     <a id="the_nights_avicci" class="hvr-float-shadow" href="songs/n/The_Nights_Avicci.html">The Nights - Avicci</a>
                     <a href="songs/n/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/n/.html"> </a>
                 </p>
             </div>
         <hr id="o_songs"/><hr/><p align="center">O</p><hr/>
             <div>
                 <p>
                     <a id="on_my_mind_ellie_goulding" class="hvr-float-shadow" href="songs/o/On_My_Mind_Ellie_Goulding.html">On My Mind - Ellie Goulding</a>
                     <a href="songs/o/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/o/.html"> </a>
                 </p>
             </div>
         <hr id="p_songs"/><hr/><p align="center">P</p><hr/>
             <div>
                 <p>
                     <a id="paradise_coldplay" class="hvr-float-shadow" href="songs/p/Paradise_Coldplay.html">Paradise - Coldplay</a>
                     <a href="songs/p/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/p/.html"> </a>
                 </p>
             </div>
         <hr id="q_songs"/><hr/><p align="center">Q</p><hr/>
             <div>
                 <p>
                     <a href="songs/q/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/q/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/q/.html"> </a>
                 </p>
             </div>
         <hr id="r_songs"/><hr/><p align="center">R</p><hr/>
             <div>
                 <p>
                     <a id="rather_be_clean_bandit" class="hvr-float-shadow" href="songs/r/Rather_Be_Clean_Bandit.html">Rather Be - Clean Bandit</a>
                     <a href="songs/r/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/r/.html"> </a>
                 </p>
             </div>
         <hr id="s_songs"/><hr/><p align="center">S</p><hr/>
             <div>
                 <p>
                     <a id="secrets_coldplay" class="hvr-float-shadow" href="songs/s/Secrets_Coldplay.html">Secrets - Coldplay</a>
                     <a href="songs/s/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/s/.html"> </a>
                 </p>
             </div>
         <hr id="t_songs"/><hr/><p align="center">T</p><hr/>
             <div>
                 <p>
                     <a id="this_is_how_we_do_katy_perry" class="hvr-float-shadow" href="songs/t/This_Is_How_We_Do_Katy_Perry.html">This Is How We Do - Katy Perry</a>
                     <a href="songs/t/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/t/.html"> </a>
                 </p>
             </div>
         <hr id="u_songs"/><hr/><p align="center">U</p><hr/>
             <div>
                 <p>
                     <a id="uma_thurman_fall_out_boy" class="hvr-float-shadow" href="songs/u/Uma_Thurman_Fall_Out_Boy.html">Uma Thurman - Fall Out Boy</a>
                     <a href="songs/u/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/u/.html"> </a>
                 </p>
             </div>
         <hr id="v_songs"/><hr/><p align="center">V</p><hr/>
             <div>
                 <p>
                     <a id="victorious_panic_at_the_disco" class="hvr-float-shadow" href="songs/v/Victorious_Panic_At_The_Disco.html">Victorious - Panic! At The Disco</a>
                     <a href="songs/v/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/v/.html"> </a>
                 </p>
             </div>
         <hr id="w_songs"/><hr/><p align="center">W</p><hr/>
             <div>
                 <p>
                     <a id="want_to_want_me_jason_derulo" class="hvr-float-shadow" href="songs/w/Want_To_Want_Me_Jason_Derulo.html">Want To Want Me - Jason Derulo</a>
                     <a href="songs/w/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/w/.html"> </a>
                 </p>
             </div>
         <hr id="x_songs"/><hr/><p align="center">X</p><hr/>
             <div>
                 <p>
                     <a id="xo_the_eden_project" class="hvr-float-shadow" href="songs/x/XO_The_Eden_Project.html">XO - The Eden Project</a>
                     <a href="songs/x/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/x/.html"> </a>
                 </p>
             </div>
         <hr id="y_songs"/><hr/><p align="center">Y</p><hr/>
             <div>
                 <p>
                     <a id="you_know_you_like_it_dj_snake" class="hvr-float-shadow" href="songs/y/You_Know_You_Like_It_DJ_Snake.html">You Know You Like It - DJ Snake</a>
                     <a href="songs/y/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/y/.html"> </a>
                 </p>
             </div>
         <hr id="z_songs"/><hr/><p align="center">Z</p><hr/>
             <div>
                 <p>
                     <a href="songs/z/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/z/.html"> </a>
                     <a href="songs/z/.html"> </a>
                 </p>
             </div>
     </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your info page your links needs to contain the homepage url and the section that you want to jump, for example:

```
     <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="homepage/#z_songs">Z</a></li>
     <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="homepage/#a_songs">A</a></li>
     <li><a class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" href="homepage/#b_songs">B</a></li>
```

You can try it at http://plnkr.co/edit/iwFCnryOKJS9zMGRmbeI?p=preview

Only "All Of Me - John Legend" goes to a info page.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your **Info** section of the song i.e (All Of Me - John Legend). Create an element with an `id`, then add this `id to your link, like:

```
<a id="all_of_me_john_legend" class="hvr-float-shadow" href="songs/a/All_Of_Me_John_Legend.html#info">All Of Me - John Legend</a>
```

Note the `href`:

```
href="songs/a/All_Of_Me_John_Legend.html#info"
```

This will go to the song page and to the `info` section.